# Multiple SELECT variables are not displaying

Tags: php, html, mysql

Having issues displaying all of the selected data entries inside SELECT. Right now the only one that is displaying is the recipe_direct data. Each table data should list in one row the name, ingred, direct, auth name and auth email.

```
  <div class="starter-template">
    <h1>Recipes</h1>
  </div>
  <?php
    try
    {
      $sql = 'SELECT recipe_id, recipe_name, recipe_ingred, recipe_direct, author_name, author_email FROM recipes';
      $result = $pdo->query($sql);
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
      $error = 'Error fetching recipes: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
    while ($row = $result->fetch())
    {
      $recipes[$row['recipe_id']] = $row;
    }
  ?>

  <p><a href="addrecipe.php">Add a Recipe</a></p>
  <?php foreach ($recipes as $id => $recipe): ?>
    <blockquote>
      <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $recipe['recipe_name']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $recipe['recipe_ingred']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $recipe['recipe_direct']; ?></td> 
          <td><?php echo $recipe['author_name']; ?></td> 
          <td><?php echo $recipe['author_email']; ?></td>
        </tr>
          <?php htmlout($recipe_html); ?> | 
          <a href="updaterecipe.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>">edit</a> |
          <a href="deleterecipe.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>">delete</a>
      </table>
    </blockquote>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: For one thing *and as a sidenote,* your table tags should be outside the loop.

Comment: i don't know what `htmlout()` does but clearly `$repice_html` is being overwritten, thus getting the last value assigned by `$recipe['recipe_direct']`, and no need for that foreach, just use `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You overwrite `$recipe_html` each time you assign a value to it

why not just echo out the table rows:

```
  <table>
     <?php foreach ($recipes as $id => $recipe): ?>
     <tr>
      <td><?= $recipe['recipe_name']; ?></td>
      <td><?= $recipe['recipe_ingred']; ?></td>
      <td><?= $recipe['recipe_direct']; ?></td> 
      <td><?= $recipe['author_name']; ?></td> 
      <td><?= $recipe['author_email']; ?></td>
    </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
 </table>
```

**EdIt** as @Fred -ii- states, the table tags should be outside the loop

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks correct up until your `foreach`.

```
<blockquote>
  <table class="table table-striped">
   <?php foreach ($recipes as $id => $recipe): ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php $recipe_html = $recipe['recipe_name']; ?></td>
      <td><?php $recipe_html = $recipe['recipe_ingred']; ?></td>
      <td><?php $recipe_html = $recipe['recipe_direct']; ?></td> 
      <td><?php $recipe['author_name']; ?></td> 
      <td><?php $recipe['author_email']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <p> //seems you were missing opening <p> tag//
      <?php htmlout($recipe_html); ?> | 
      <a href="updaterecipe.php?id=<?=$id?>">edit</a> | //can use shorthand here//
      <a href="deleterecipe.php?id=<?=$id?>">delete</a> //can use shorthand here//
    </p>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
   </table>
</blockquote>
```